# What might cause my tyre to deflate to a certain point and then remain there?

Tags: tire, puncture

This doesn't make sense to me. If I inflate my tyre to max I can cycle to work. Later on, the tyre is a bit deflated. Enough to be OK to ride on if I'm careful about potholes. However it never deflates any further. I left it all weekend and checked it and it's exactly the same level of deflatedness.

I'm about to switch out the inner tube but before I do I was hoping to discover why, in case I waste an inner tube.

I would expect a slow puncture to make it go completely flat.

Comment: Aha that does look like a duplicate, feel free to close.

Comment: It's interesting in that it's a differently phrased question that leads to the same answer.